# copying files from Folder & it's sub folders to another location folders with batch file where Excel Macros & Command not running automatically

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, batch-file

I am copying files from one specific Folder & it's sub folders  to  server location specific folder using batch file where I am unable to run the Macro and command tabs in Excel file automatically.

I am running below batch file and than running macros and commands in excel is working fine

```
@Powershell -NoP -C "GCI $(GCI \"H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\"|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,CreationTime|Export-csv -NoT \"D:\Source\Bhavesh.csv\""
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\excel.exe" "d:\source\macro_Molding.xlsm"
"taskkill /IM "powershell.exe" /F"
```

But when I want to run Excel Macro and command tabs also including in batch file as below → Macro not running

```
@Powershell -NoP -C "GCI $(GCI \"H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\"|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,CreationTime|Export-csv -NoT \"D:\Source\Bhavesh.csv\""
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\excel.exe" "d:\source\macro_Molding.xlsm"
    $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
    $excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\fso -Include *.xls, *.xlsm -Recurse
    Foreach($file in $excelFiles)
    {
       $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file.fullname)
       $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
       $excel.Run("MoldData_Copy")
       $workbook.save()
       $workbook.close()
    }
    $excel.quit()

"taskkill /IM "powershell.exe" /F"
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Windows is this supposed to be for?

Comment: Seems like `$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application` will create a separate instance of Excel, so unless every file you're opening in that loop contains the macro "MoldData_Copy" you need to re-think this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you do not have the module name in the run command.

This vbs code works for me:

```
ExcelFilePath = "\\FS06\Users6\a78208\Dokument\Skrivare Landskrona.xlsm"
MacroPath = "Modul1.uppdatera"


On Error Resume Next
Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If ExcelApp is Nothing then
   set newExcel = True
   Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If


ExcelApp.Visible = True
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
ExcelApp.Run MacroPath
wb.Save

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

If newExcel then
  wb.Close
  ExcelApp.Quit
end if
```

So I believe your code need to replace this:

```
$excel.Run("MoldData_Copy")
```

with:

```
$excel.Run("Module1.MoldData_Copy")
```

Or what you have called the module in the Excel VBA editor

Comment: I have tried with Module1.MoldData_Copy however still other functions are working from batch file but Macro not working.

Comment: Check what the name of the module is. It's not sure it is Module1.